# How should I be configuring my VirtualHosts?

Tags: linux, hosting, virtualhost, apache

I have a site to work on, because of the way the URLs are built the application seems to have been created on the assumption that it will be at the server root (only app).

On my dev server I have other projects and up to now a simple symlink has been working for me, but that's not the case now because this new app wants to sit at the route and process all URLs arriving on :80.

Hopefully this snippet from httpd.conf will help explain what I'm trying to acheive:

```
# default for any not matched elsewhere
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/newproject
</VirtualHost>
# now try to pick out specific URLs
<VirtualHost localhost/webdev>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/existingProject
 ServerName localhost/project
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Google `name based virtual hosting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice:

Add a value in your hosts file so that you can route that one specific app to another domain such has localhost2.  Then add a second virtual host with Servername localhost2.  This also, should probably have been asked on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Travis. I ended up adding a "Listen 81" directive in httpd.conf and setting the newproject VirtualHost to listen to *:81.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a "Listen 81" directive in httpd.conf and setting the newproject VirtualHost to listen to *:81